# How do I build an Image from multiple smaller Images

Tags: java, 2d-games

So I am making this adventure/progression game and for the font I am using tiles from a spriteSheet (each tile is a letter) which I will use for many different purposes, and I can't figure out why my program is returning a black Image instead of an Image built from smaller Images (each containing a letter). The program works when I return the **scaledImage** Image but that only returns a single letter. What is supposed to happen is I divide the word in a letter and use a **BufferedImage** and **Graphics2D** to get the matching letter from the spriteSheet, that part works, but when I draw it to the Buffered Image, it returns a black Image.

```
BufferedImage spriteSheet;
    String[] alphabet = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
            "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " " };

public ImageIcon getWord(String word, int x, int size) throws IOException {

        String tempLetter;
        try {
            spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("img/SpriteSheet.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Image testImage = null;

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(size * word.length(), size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D wordImage = bi.createGraphics();
        Image subImage;
        Image scaledImage;
        

        for (int l = 0; l < word.length(); l++) {
            tempLetter = word.substring(l, l + 1);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {

                if (tempLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(alphabet[i])) {
                     subImage = spriteSheet.getSubimage(2 + (2 * i) + (i * 200), 2, 200, 200);
                     scaledImage = subImage.getScaledInstance(size, size, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                    wordImage.drawImage(scaledImage, l*size, 0, null);
                    testImage = scaledImage;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }

        wordImage.dispose();

        File wordFile = new File("img/word.png");
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", wordFile);
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("img/word.png");
        wordFile.delete();

        return ic;
    }
```

This is how I call the method:

```
   JButton play = new JButton();

            play.setBounds(300, 300, 600, 150);  
            play.setIcon(sc.getWord("play", 600, 150)); 
p.add(play);
f.add(p);
```

Comment: Why are you writing the image in a file then reading it back? What are you doing with the IOException?

Comment: @RealSkeptic  I can't find another way to do it.

Comment: How about `new ImageIcon(bi)`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic that still doesn't work.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I found the error... So the letters are black and the background is also black so they were showing but I couldn't see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while of research, I found out that the reason the letters were not showing was because they are black and the background of the BufferedImage was also black. So the letters were showing but were "invisible" because of the background.